# Using the fp package inside an invoice template

Tags: fp

I am using this template :

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/invoice

And I want to kind of do something similar to this :

```
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{1000}\formatNumber{\t}}
```

And make a discount command :

```
\newcommand*{\discount}[2]{\FPmul{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{#2}\formatNumber{\t}}
```

But it should not just have the `#2` there it should be `(1-#2)/100000`, but no idea how to do that.

I assume it is just using `FPsub` and `FPdiv` but I can't get the syntax worked out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be easier to help you if you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), that is, a minimal but compilable code reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am just using the exact template as linked, and want to add one more line to it. I can copy and past the entire template from the link, just didn't see the need.

Comment: Vincent didn't say that you should copy the entire template but provide a *minimal* so small example. I at least normally don't bother to follow external links - that costs too much time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer, this is guaranteed not a sensible way to do it but :

```
\newcommand*{\discount}[2]{\setcounter{rate}{100 - #2}\setcounter{dis}{\arabic{#1} *\value{rate}}\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{dis}}{100000}\formatNumber{\t}}
```

Does it.

Allowing :

```
{\bf 10\% Discount for Prepayment } & & & {\bf \$\discount{cost}{10}} \\
```

Ideally that 10 should be a variable, not hard coded twice and there is no way the sensible way to do it is what I did but that's enough for today.

Anyone have a cleaner answer with the rate made a variable, I would be interested to read.